# PHP: add If condition within the line

Tags: php, operators, if-statement

```
    if($i==6) {
    $result .= '<a style="display:none" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;;}
    else {
    $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.$value['images']['low_resolution']['url'].'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;}
```

This means: for all the items greater than 6 `$result` is `display:none` and blahblah, for all the others $result is images with caption.

What I'd like to add is: if counter is EQUAL to 4, print the "else" `$result` with the ONLY change that instead of `src="'.$value['images']['low_resolution']['url'].'"`, it would be `src="'.$value['images']['thumb_resolution']['url'].'"`

I think that this would work, but I'm looking for a cooler, one-liner way :D

```
    if($i==6) {
    $result .= '<a style="display:none" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;;}
    elseif($i===4) {
    $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.$value['images']['thumb_resolution']['url'].'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;}
    else {
    $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.$value['images']['low_resolution']['url'].'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;}
```

Comment: Ternary expressions really can make your code hard to read especially with the long lines you have. If they were simple single values. Then it would a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the conditional operator, or ternary operator. It is used like this:

```
$check = true;
$var = $check ? 5 : 3;
```

The conditional operator checks the value of the expression before the `?` and outputs either the value before the `:` if the expression is true or the value after the ':' if it is false. So the line above sets `$var` to 5 because `$check` is true. You could also have done this:

```
$check = 2354;
$var = ($check < 40) ? 5 : 3;
```

That would have given you the opposite result, `$var` would have been set to 3, because `$check` did not meet the condition `$check < 40`. Think of it like a function which outputs one of two possible values based on the truth value of a given expression. You can embed that directly into the `result .=` as:

```
($i === 4) ? $value['images']['low_resolution']['url'] : $value['images']['thumb_resolution']['url'];
```

For more information about the conditional operator, you can look at the PHP documentation page about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Note that the part about the conditional operator is a little way down the page.

Comment: There error there might be that the whole conditional statement needs to be in parentheses when its embedded.

Comment: Remove these: `if($i==6) {
 $result .= '<a style="display:none" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL`;`;}
  else {
  $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.($i === 4) ? $value['images']['low_resolution']['url'] : $value['images']['thumb_resolution']['url']`;`.'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;}
        }`

Comment: Those semicolons that I isolated may be the problem. I don't think you intended to put two semicolons after the first `PHP_EOL`, and you don't put the semicolon after the conditional statement, it acts like a function, you can put it inside statements and it will evaluate without a semicolon. Surround the the conditional statement by parentheses after making that edit. That may also cause a problem.

Comment: I used the code on your comment above but I got a "syntax error, unexpected '.'"

Comment: Remove the two unhighlighted semicolons, and add parentheses around the conditional statement. See if that works for you. You should probably fix the formatting, too, or tomorrow you won't be able to understand it. Sorry, I didn't have enough space in the comment to make it neater.

Comment: I used this (removed unhighlighted semicolons): http://pastebin.com/VUJ3pFUv
But I just get $value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] printed (no other tag), the links one after the other.

Comment: Put parentheses around the conditional statement. It won't work otherwise. There was a comment about it on the PHP documentation page for the conditional statement. I linked to the page above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ternary operator](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51638-the-ternary-operator-in-php/) of php. The simple syntax is

```
Condition ? (if-equivalent-statement) : (else-equivalent-statement)
```

However, when this condition is used inside another statement, you should enclose it within parentheses like:

```
(Condition ? (if-equivalent-statement) : (else-equivalent-statement))
```

So, the code should be like this:

```
if($i==6) {
    $result .= '<a style="display:none" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;;}
else {
//I've broken down the line to make it easier to read

    $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.

            (($i==4) ? $value['images']['thumb_resolution']['url'] : $value['images']['low_resolution']['url'])

            .'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;

}
```

Comment: The dots at the beginning of the last 2 lines gave me 500 internal server error so I used this:
http://pastebin.com/Q81f1ncc but the else $result isn't printed at all..

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno sorry, that was a mistake. I've modified the code now removing the dots and enclosed the whole `:?` by parentheses. That should work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

What you might be thinking is a Ternary operators but it doesn't "really" support `elseif` and can be hard to read.

Why not try a switch for more cooler but it's not one liner. :)

```
 switch ($i){
   case "6": 
       $result .= '<a style="display:none" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;
       break;
   case "4": 
       $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.$value['images']['thumb_resolution']['url'].'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;
       break;
   default:  
       $result .= "\t".'<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'"><img id="thumb'.++$i.'" src="'.$value['images']['low_resolution']['url'].'" alt="'.$value['caption']['text'].'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a> '.$caption.PHP_EOL;
       break;
 }
```

Comment: I don't know why but with this the "thumb5" image isn't displayed! :o

Comment: What is the "thumb5"? Is that the iteration or something? Do you have this in a loop?

Comment: thumb5 is from id="thumb'.++$i.'"